# Connecting to a database in monogolab via mongojs

Tags: node.js, mlab, mongojs

I have a node server and until now my database was local, but now I need it to be on mongolab.

Could you tell me how to connect to the database, please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **https://mongolab.com/databases/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME**
2. [**Copy the URI from your database's page on Mongolab.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMey2.jpg)
3. Use `var db = mongojs('mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ds043497.mongolab.com:43497/heroku_app14986764', ['CollectionName']);`

And you'll be connected. I did not test this.